# drupal core install module and change the enable link to work with module_filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using the filter module which makes it easier to manage modules which uses "/admin/modules?filter=" to list specific modules.

Since in core when installing new modules it displays the "enable newly added module" link, which actually only links to all modules,

I was wondering if it might be possible to create a custom module that replaces that link and redirects instead to "/admin/modules?filter=NEWLY_INSTALLED_MODULES_SEPARATED_BY_%20" ?

https://www.drupal.org/project/module_filter/issues/2952200#comment-12584379

Comment: Hey Markus, it's hard to tell what exactly you are asking for or what exactly do you have problems with. The short answer to your question is: Yes, it's possible. Everything you can imagine is possible. But at what costs? So please try to share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll see how we can help you out :)

Comment: @leymannx I struggled to explain clearly, sorry :) Hope you understand the issue that when installing new modules, the hyperlink "enable newly added module" doesn't actually link directly to enable them?

A solution possibly could be utilising module_filter which provides a search for modules and thus the hyperlink could point to a search string, which then at least would **display the newly installed module/s where the user can simply click on enable**.

Comment: But what have you tried so far?

Comment: Since installing+enabling modules seems a common task and this module is very popular, it could be really worthwhile to implement this. 
I'm happy to provide more details if this reasonably doable and the best approach to this. (I don't think core can be changes as I would expect implementing a search result for certain modules be even more complex where this module already provides it and nicely integrates).

Comment: I totally agree this seems like an useful feature. But what have you tried so far to fix this issue yourself?

Comment: Not sure how to start or what best way is to see what is being used in core to create that hyperlink, so it can be altered (after extracting the module name that becomes known during install). I know dsm(devel) to look into fields on pages but here am bit stuck for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169672/discussion-between-markus-and-leymannx).